# Is there anything like g_form.showFieldMsg for GlideDialogWindow popup? (ServiceNow)

Tags: javascript, html, servicenow

Is there anything like  g_form.showFieldMsg which shows an error message under the field for GlideDialogWindow popup (ui page) in ServiceNow?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, but here's what I've learned:

What you need to do is add a parameter to the UI page which you can then use in the client script as it renders. 
So you'd do something in the client script for the UI page, like:

```
if (sysparm_fieldMessage) {
    element.showFieldMessage(sysparm_fieldMessage + '');
}
```

then in your calling code, you'd need to do something like:

```
gdw.setPreference('sysparm_fieldMessage', 'this is my message');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use for Error : g_form.showFieldMsg('field_name_here', "your_message",'error');
or just for information : g_form.showFieldMsg('field_name_here', "your_message",'info');